# Caldera forms - Front-end edition with custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

i'm using **caldera forms** to do front end edition. I've got a problem with custom taxonomies : i want to prepopulate checkboxes with custom taxonomies terms.

Terms associated with my post should be checked. but it doesn't work.

Anyone has an idea ? Thanks a lot.

( i'm working with latest versions of wordpress, and caldera forms plugin)

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: thanks for commenting.

Comment: thanks for commenting. I've got no code example because i'm working on caldera forms interface.
In my edition form, all text values are ok ( i mean with the pre edition value), but doesn t work with taxonomies.
well, sorry for my bad english explanations